# Sharepoint: Pulling String information from a list item to populate external URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions

I am working with Sharepoint 2013, and I have a list of items that have a client id. These client ids are references to a database referenced by another group. I am wanting to pull the string information from a list item to populate a variable in a URL for a Custom Action. Please see example for clarification.

[image]

I want to extract the actual ClientID to insert into a URL when clicked.
(i.e. https://mywebsite.com/customerno=[ClientID_from_List_1]/showall.aspx

So if I clicked CASABONITAS ClientID in Sharepoint it would open a new page with the URL being https://mywebsite.com/customerno=345678/showall.aspx

I have done some [searching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/urls-and-tokens-in-sharepoint) and cannot find any customized tokens that can be used for extracting this information, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it in a Custom Action, you can retrieve the Selected Item ID and then pass that in to your Custom Action JavaScript block and retrieve the 'ClientID' as a property.

Here's a post that does something similar:
[Field Value Custom Action](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e7b324a7-c96f-4431-a7e1-3676efb70eb1/get-field-value-of-list-item-in-custom-action-through-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

As another potential solution: You could probably just create a Hyperlink Column and use a Workflow to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tokens that could get information from your custom filed value. You need to use some custom js to achieve this.

If you create custom action through sp designer, you can use `javascript: /* put your js here */` in the "Navigate to URL" box.

Besides, here is an easier option for you: use calculated column instead.